# In R, how to remove everything before the last slash

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have a dataset say

```
x <- c('test/test/my', 'et/tom/cat', 'set/eat/is', 'sk / handsome')
```

I'd like to remove everything before (including) the last slash, the result should look like

```
my cat is handsome
```

I googled this code which gives me everything before the last slash

```
gsub('(.*)/\\w+', '\\1', x)
[1] "test/test" "et/tom"    "set/eat"   "sk / tie"
```

How can I change this code,  so that the other part of the string after the last slash can be shown?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You can use `basename`:

```
paste(trimws(basename(x)),collapse=" ")
# [1] "my cat is handsome"
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `strsplit`

```
> sapply(strsplit(x, "/\\s*"), tail, 1)
   [1] "my"       "cat"      "is"       "handsome"
```

Another way for `gsub`

```
> gsub("(.*/\\s*(.*$))", "\\2", x) # without 'unwanted' spaces
[1] "my"       "cat"      "is"       "handsome"
```

Using `str_extract` from `stringr` package

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract(x, "\\w+$") # without 'unwanted' spaces
[1] "my"       "cat"      "is"       "handsome"
```

Comment: `strsplit`  with `sapply` and `tail` is a really nice way to do this. It follows the natural logic of the problem directly: find the string after the last slash.

Comment: @Jan, now without 'unwanted' spaces.

Answer (score 4):

You can basically just move where the parentheses are in the regex you already found:

```
gsub('.*/ ?(\\w+)', '\\1', x)
```

Comment: Good answer, but there is only one substitution so, `sub` would make more sense than `gsub`.  Also why just one blank after the slash?   why not `\\s*` ?

Comment: @G5W This answer follows the principle of "change as little of the OPs implementation as possible to get the desired behavior". There are a variety of ways to tinker or "improve" a regex. Personally, I like Jilbers solution best. But it's always nice to see someone answer with the simplest change.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
x <- c('test/test/my', 'et/tom/cat', 'set/eat/is', 'sk / handsome')
gsub('^(?:[^/]*/)*\\s*(.*)', '\\1', x)
```

Which yields

```
[1] "my"       "cat"      "is"       "handsome"
```

To have it in one sentence, you could `paste` it:

```
(paste0(gsub('^(?:[^/]*/)*\\s*(.*)', '\\1', x), collapse = " "))
```

---

The pattern here is:

```
^            # start of the string
(?:[^/]*/)*  # not a slash, followed by a slash, 0+ times
\\s*         # whitespaces, eventually
(.*)         # capture the rest of the string
```

This is replaced by `\\1`, hence the content of the first captured group.

Comment: @angel0smile thank users who answer your question by upvoting (when you're able), and selecting their answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers